# Android adding new contacts in sim

Tags: android, android-contacts

When we add `new contact` and select option `save to sim`, does the contact also saved in `RawContacts` and `Contacts` table. And also when we view all contacts in phone using `contact application` does it shows sim contacts from sim or sim contacts are saved in Contacts table and contact application shows sim contacts from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
            // add a row to the RawContacts table
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.anddroid.contacts.sim");
     values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "SIM");
     Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);

            // get the ID of the newly-added line
     long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);

            // add a "name" line to the Data table, linking it to the new RawContact
            // with the CONTACT_ID column
     values.clear();
     values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
     values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
     values.put(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Name");
     cr.insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
            // this insert succeeds

            // add a "phone" line to the Data table, linking it to the new RawContact
            // with the CONTACT_ID column
     values.clear();
     values.put(Data.CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
     values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
     values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "+12345678901");
     values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
     cr.insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
            // this insert fails with a NullPointerException
}
catch(Exception e){
    String xx=e.toString();
    System.out.println(xx);
}
```